# Making code work dynamically on iOS 7 and iOS 8 for checking notification status

Tags: ios, compilation

I am missing something here. I have code which checks the notification types set for a given application by using :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes]
```

However this is not valid in iOS 8 and it needs

```
[UIApplication currentUserNotificationSettings]
```

The issue is that I want to

1. Compile this with iOS 7.x
2. At run time decide which one to use..

How do I get this working? Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's generally recommended to check for features (instead of the iOS version):

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
    // use registerUserNotificationSettings
} else {
    // use enabledRemoteNotificationTypes
}
```

Source: App Programming Guide for iOS > Supporting Multiple Versions of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 if ( [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 8.0 )
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
 else
       [UIApplication currentUserNotificationSettings];
```

Comment: Although this is a good answer, checking to see if the class responds to the method is the ideal solution.